# How to check task assigning time for a user in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have table task_manager like this,

```
task_id | from_time | to_time | user_id | 
=========================================
  1     |   10:30   |  12:00  |   1
  2     |   16:00   |  17:30  |   1
  3     |   12:00   |  14:00  |   1
```

if i use the following query , i can get the first record.

SELECT * FROM `task_manager`
WHERE from_time <= '11:30'  AND   to_time >= '12:00';

But i want to check the time for user the time between 11:30 to 12:30.
how to get the result for first & last records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM task_manager WHERE (from_time >= '11:30' AND from_time <= '12:30') OR (to_time >= '11:30' AND to_time <= '12:30');
```

Comment: No it fetches all records

Comment: Great! Please accept this answer now (click on "V").

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT * FROM task_manager WHERE from_time >= '11:30' AND to_time <= '12:30' limit 2;
```

Comment: what have you changed, I do not see any change.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will work if your time columns are correctly date/time formatted.

```
SELECT column_name(s) 
FROM task_manager 
WHERE from_time >= '11:30' AND to_time <= '12:30' limit 2;
```